# F# interactive - Is it possible to step into a project from opened solution or a symbol file

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

While debugging, does F# interactive support stepping into projects from an opened solution or a dll with symbols file?

During usual debug sessions from a console app or unit tests, Visual Studio is smart enough to step into a project that is opened even in another instance of VS (at least for C#). But in FSI, it doesn't step into a project in the same instance of VS. Is it supposed to?

```
#I @"../../Bin/Debug"
#r "PorjectOpenedInTheSameVSorHasSymbols.dll"
```

Comment: You can't step into an existing project with fsi

Comment: @JohnPalmer Could you please make it an answer if your are sure, because a had googled it before asking. It looks like the debugging machinery in FSI is the same one than powers VS, so I hoped there is some trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FSI can't be used to step into a running process